# When trying to visualise "regular" grid points generated by numpy.meshgrid() I am seeing white vertical lines. Why is that the case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

When the grid is uniform, I believe one must not see the vertical lines which in my opinion indicates "gap" in data points.
The following code replicates my issue.[The plot is shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGs7D.png)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0,100,1)
y = np.arange(0,100,1)
xmesh,ymesh = np.meshgrid(x,y)
plt.scatter(xmesh,ymesh,s=0.5)
# or plt.plot(xmesh,ymesh,'k.',ms=1)
```

Comment: add `plt.axis('equal')` to your script.  If you're plotting from `spyder`, hit `ctrl+enter` after `plt.scatter(...)` to add another line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the result of a [Moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) due to the difference in spacial frequency between your points and the pixel grid of your screen.

To fix the problem, increase the size of your figure/Axes so that you have enough pixels to show all the points in your data.

see for example the difference between these two plots:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.scatter(xmesh,ymesh,s=0.5)
```

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.scatter(xmesh,ymesh,s=0.5)
```

[image]